# iOS: How to add conditionality based on Project Target

Tags: ios, target

I am building a project that will eventually be compiled to make 4 slightly different applications. The main change I have to make are image changes, but I also want to change a few UILabels as well.

I know that I could create multiple XIB files and modify them to be attached to each target, but I would is there a way to use a macro #define if to detect the name of the target?

Example: Project: Project1
Targets: TargetA, TargetB

```
#define if Target = TargetA{
label.text = @"This is targetA";
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to submit four nearly-identical apps to the app store?

Comment: Ad hoc distribution, the app needs to be regionalized (as in the Washington app has different content than our Florida app) and I am trying to handle all the changes in a single project. If changes need to be made Id like to avoid having to make then in 4 different projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do this... you can access the bundle identifier which is unique for each target:

NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);

Answer (score 0):

C preprocess macro will accomplish this feature.

In Xcode:

```
TARGET->Build Settings->Preprocess Marcos
```

And your source code:

```
#if DEBUG
    // debug build
#else
    // release build
#endif
```

This is already defined macro. You can define your own macros in all project targets.